# isNaN not catching letters

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, nan

I have JS code to validate a Zip Code: 10 numeric chars with a dash in the 6th position (e.g., 12345-6789). I verify that both parts are numbers using `!isNaN`.

```
if (valSize == 10) {
    var numVal1 = new Number(newVal.substring(0, 4));
    var numVal2 = new Number(newVal.substring(6, 9));
    if (newVal.charAt(5) == '-' && !isNaN(numVal1) && !isNaN(numVal2)) {
        return newVal;
    }
}
throw "Incorrect format";
```

This mostly works, but for some reason the following value goes through, and an error is NOT returned:

```
12345-678a
```

Why is !IsNaN(substring(6,9)) allowed to pass in this case?

Comment: Side note: Some people say exceptions should be used for *exceptional* things, and input validation isn't exactly exceptional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`String.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) function signature is:

```
str.substring(indexA[, indexB])
```

> **indexA**
>
> An integer between 0 and the length of the string, specifying the
>   offset into the string of the first character to include in the
>   returned substring.
>
> **indexB**
>
> Optional. An integer between 0 and the length of the string, which
>   specifies the offset into the string of the first character **NOT** to
>   include in the returned substring.

So you have:

```
"12345-678a".substring(0,4) // 1234
"12345-678a".substring(6,9) // 678
```

So either correct the indices:

```
"12345-678a".substring(0,5) // 12345
"12345-678a".substring(6)   // 678a
```

Or use [`String.substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

---

Or use regex (recommended) since your current code, after fixing, would happily accept `12.45-67.8`, `+1234--678` and `12e45-6e-9`. All you need to do is this:

```
/^\d{5}-\d{4}$/.test("12345-678a") // false
/^\d{5}-\d{4}$/.test("12.45-67.8") // false
/^\d{5}-\d{4}$/.test("12345-6789") // true
```

Comment: It's worth it to note that `"12345-678a".substr(6,9) // 678a`

Answer (score 2):

Would a regex not be the more proper test?

```
/\d{5}-\d{4}/.test('12345-1234')
true

/\d{5}-\d{4}/.test('12345-123a')
false
```

Answer (score 1):

`newVal.substring(6,9)` in the case of the string "12345-678a" would return "678" which is a number. So there should **not** be an error thrown.